# Mstest takes longer to run when using teamcity

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, mstest, teamcity-9.0

I have a teamcity build that runs tests using the mstest2012 test runner. The duration of tests were reasonable but over time it became slower and slower to the point that it takes almost an hour to run.

When running the tests using the standalone mstest.exe on the build server on the same dlls it takes only a few minutes.

I looked at the mstest logs of both of the executions methods(team city and standalone) and didn't see any difference in the steps but some of them took longer to run on the build execution.

I disabled the code coverage on team city which reduced the amount of time but there is still a very big time difference.

Has anyone encountered such kind of a problem?

**Edit:**
At the end I gave up and migrated to NUnit which reduced the time significally

Comment: I actually have the same problem. My TeamCity builds (only sometimes) take much more time for execution. I already tired to do a manual cleanup. Sometimes it helps sometimes not